# Change XmlRootElement annotation name by using binding

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, jaxb, xjb

I am trying to convert my xsd files to java objects by using jax-b plugin (This plugin reads my xsd files and convert them to models). Since I have two xsd's with Request and Response schema.

In both schemas , I have same root element name i.e XML. Somebody suggested me that instead of creating binding file to overcome the conflicts of having same name, use different names on both xsd's.

I applied the changes. However when my jax-b do marshalling and unmarshalling it converts to the new name I provided.

Example:

**REQUEST**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
      <xs:element name="RequestXML"> 
</xs:schema>
```

**RESPONSE**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
      <xs:element name="ResponseXML"> 
</xs:schema>
```

By Jax-b plugin it creates me:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "RequestXML")
public class RequestXML


@XmlRootElement(name = "ResponseXML")
public class ResponseXML
```

Marshalling

```
<RequestXML>
    <HEADER></HEADER>
    <CUSTOMER></CUSTOMER>
</RequestXML>
```

However My request should be

```
<XML>
    <HEADER></HEADER>
    <CUSTOMER></CUSTOMER>
</XML>
```

Please suggest me solution. Can I use binding while creating my objects?
I dont want to change manually rootElement name to XML

Please reply

Comment: What issues do you get if both root elements are `XML`?

Comment: my jax-b plugin could able to generate duplicate classes

Comment: Then can't you have your classes named differently in Java and you the `name` attribute of the `@XmlRootElement` annotation to call them both `XML`?

Comment: I can have but my classes are autogenerated by plugin and I dont want to touch my classes manually.